# Issue while trying to display images from display on carousel slider

Tags: php

I currently trying to make it where My Database is storing image names like slider1.jpg and then I'm retrieving that from my database, but the issue is when I'm selecting * all from the table its only displaying the first link in the table. Any Ideas on how I can fix this in my code?

Heres my PHP:

```
    <?php
        //Gets Links
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM slider');
    $stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
     $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        extract($row);
}

?>
```

And Heres my Carousel Slider.

```
 <header>
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
          <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('images/slider/<?php echo $row['link'];?>')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>First Slide</h3>
              <p>This is a description for the first slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('images/slider/<?php echo $row['link'];?>')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>Second Slide</h3>
              <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('images/slider/<?php echo $row['link'];?>')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>Third Slide</h3>
              <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to utilize a loop on the results so you can build each slide with a new $row from the database query:

```
<?php
// build a clean array of slides from the db grab
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM slider');
$stmt->execute();
$slides = [];
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $slides = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>

.... starter html ....

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <?php foreach($slides as $i => $slide) { ?>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" 
              data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;?>" 
              class="<?php echo (!$i?'active':'');?>"></li>
       <?php }?>
    </ol>

.... more html ....

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <?php foreach($slides as $i => $slide) { ?>

      <div class="carousel-item <?php echo (!$i?'active':'');?>" 
           style="background-image: url('images/slider/<?php echo $slide['link'];?>')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3><?php echo $slide['slide_name'];?></h3>
          <p><?php echo $slide['slide_desc'];?></p>
        </div>
      </div>

   <?php } ?>
</div>

.... the rest of your html output ....
```

Comment: I tried that Code, and nothing is happening. Theres just a Lot of blank Space.

Comment: When I put `div class="carousel-time active" it will display all the images but all at once not in the carousel.

Comment: I changed the slide_desc_field to slide_desc and slide_name_field to slide_name

Comment: Active on both the carousel item and on the controls makes it be the first slide when you load the page.

Comment: It's Alright, I had no clue on how to pull from the database in the first place! Thank You for helping me!

Comment: Ok, total new setup. This grabs the rows into an array first (since you loop on them twice), then does the looping. An index helps keeps things cleaner/easier too. Cleaned up my comments too ;)

Comment: If you need to know what I'm doing with this: `!$i` ... its just a simple way to say the first indexed row, since the first index is zero, not zero = true :)

Comment: Ahhh. :) Thank You!